# Ext - Dynamic Columns triggered by an event

Tags: extjs

I have a Viewport and in Center region I have a tabpanel.Each tabpanel contain columns, and each column has panel with 3-4 items. Something like...

Column A(Week 1)                                       Column B(Week 2)
Item A1 Item B1

Item A2   item B2

I want these columns to be dynamic. If columns were a week of calendar then once the month changes,the columns also change.I also have a small calendar in the east region of this viewport and I am planning to trigger the column change using that calendar.

Here is the code...

```
<title>Test</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/ext-all.css" />

<!-- Tabs Example Files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tabs-example.css" />
<!-- Common Styles for the examples -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../shared/examples.css" />



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/ext-all.css"/>

    <!-- GC -->
    <!-- LIBS -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../adapter/ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <!-- ENDLIBS -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext_main.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">

  Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();
     var store = new Ext.data.Store({

        data: [ ],

        reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader({id:'id'}, [
            'id',
            'St',
            'GD',
            'DC',
            'T',
            {name: 'DP', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'}
        ])
    });

var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({

layout: 'border',

renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

 items: [{

region: 'north',

title: '',

height: 24,

 xtype: 'toolbar',

 items: [{

 xtype: 'tbspacer'
  },{

  xtype: 'tbbutton',

  text: '',

 handler: function(btn){

  btn.disable();
    }
  },{
    xtype: 'tbfill'
  },
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: '<b></b>',
         menu: [


        ]}

]


  },{
    region: 'west',
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Calendar',
    collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    width: 280,

    html:'<object data=http://localhost:8084/TM/extjs/examples/layout/test.html width="400" height="220"> \n\
<embed src=http://localhost:8084/TM/extjs/examples/layout/test.html width="400" height="220"> </embed></object>'

  },{

                region: 'center',
                split:true,
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                activeTab: 0,
                items: [
                    {
                        title: ' ',
                       layout:'column',
                autoScroll:true,
                items:[{
                    columnWidth:.13,
            title: '2/21',
            xtype: 'panel',
           collapsible: true,
           items: [{
           title: '',
            height: 100,
            dataIndex: '',
             rowspan:1,
            width:200},
{
            title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan:1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            }

           ]}

           ]
           },{
               columnWidth:.13,
            title: '3/14',
            xtype: 'panel',
           collapsible: true,
           items: [{
           title: '',
            height: 100,
             rowspan:1,
            width:200},
{
            title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan:1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            }

           ]
           }

           ]
           }
                            ] },
{ title: '',
    layout:'column',
                autoScroll:true,
                items:[{
                    columnWidth:.13,
            title: '2/21',
            xtype: 'panel',
           collapsible: true,
           items: [{
           title: '',
            height: 100,
             rowspan:1,
            width:200},
{
            title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan:1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            }

           ]


    }


           ]
    }

,{
        title: '3/07',
           columnWidth:.13,
            collapsible: true,
          items: [{
           title: '',
            height: 100,
             rowspan:1,
            width:200},
{
            title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan:1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            }

           ]
    },{
        title: '3/14',
           columnWidth:.13,
            collapsible: true,
          items: [{
           title: '',
            height: 100,
             rowspan:1,
            width:200},
{
            title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan:1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            }

           ]



},
{ title: '',
       layout:'column',
                autoScroll:true,
                items:[{
                    columnWidth:.13,
            title: '2/21',
            xtype: 'panel',
           collapsible: true,
           items: [{
           title: '',
            height: 100,
             rowspan:1,
            width:200},
{
            title: ' ',
            height: 100,
            rowspan:1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            }

           ]},{
           columnWidth:.13,
            title: '2/28',
            xtype: 'panel',
           collapsible: true,
           items: [{
          title: '',
            height: 100,
             rowspan:1,
            width:200},
{
            title: ' ',
            height: 100,
            rowspan:1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            },{

             title: '',
            height: 100,
            rowspan: 1,
            width:200
            }
           ]


           }
]},
{
    region: 'east'



},
{
  region:'south',
  height: 200


 });

</script>
```

Comment: This is not a question.  Where is the question?  You need to provide sample code for us to try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `Ext.TabPanel`, use the `add()` and `remove()` methods to add or remove `Ext.Panel`s, which represent your tabs.

If you are clearing all tabs, use `removeAll()`.  Pseudo-code:

```
onChangeMonth: function() {
    // ...
    tabpanel.removeAll();
    foreach (weekPanels) {
        tabpanel.add(weekPanel);
    }
}
```